# Dictionaries to Data frame keep key integrity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This i more a question of what is the best way to achieve something.

For example if I have 3 dictionaries

```
A ={key1:1, key2:2, key3:3}
B ={key2:2, key3:3, key1:1}
C= {key3:'you', key2:'are', key1:'how'}
```

Ideally I would like to turn this in to DF with 4 columns Key,A,B,C
with each of the dictionaries becoming a columns, and ensuring that entries are inserted for the correct key?

Additionally if there was a 4th dictionary D however it only had the following entries

```
D = {key2:'some', key3:'data'}
```

Is it possible to have the 5th D column and any missing entries are given a NaN value?

Comment: Can you give a output example, I got lost in all do’s...

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'B':B, 'C':C})
        .rename_axis(index='Key')
        .reset_index()
     )

# add D
df['D'] = df['Key'].map(D)
```

Output:

```
    Key  A  B    C     D
0  key1  1  1  how   NaN
1  key2  2  2  are  some
2  key3  3  3  you  data
```